# Where does the Zohar say blessing and success come as a result of the Shabbos’s holiness?

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, zohar

The Eitz Yosef (cited in a footnote in 'The Complete Artscroll Siddur', page 316) quotes the Zohar who says:

> All the weekday blessing and success come as a result of the Shabbos’s
>   holiness. Therefore, what you put into Shabbos is what you get out of
>   it. The amount of energy (spirituality) you inject into sanctifying
>   the Shabbos, will determine the amount of blessing that will be
>   deposited into the coming week.

Where does the *Zohar* say this?

Comment: Where is the Etz Yosef? It's also interesting to note that many Seforim say that Shabbos is not dependent on our input as much as other mitzvos and holidays.

Comment: @y.lub: See 'The Complete Artscroll Siddur', page 316, note: לקראת... כי היא מקור הברכה.

Comment: הספר אינו תחת ידי כעת but tomorrow I will look it up inside and see what I can dig up unless someone beats me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in פרשת יתרו פח ע״א by זכור את יום השבת לקדשו.

You can read it online [here](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01149_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0041_L2).

> זָכוֹר אֶת יוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת לְקַדְּשׁוֹ. רַבִּי יִצְחָק אָמַר, כְּתִיב
>   (שמות כ) וַיְבָרֶךְ אֱלהִים אֶת יוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי, וּכְתִיב בַּמָּן
>   (שמות טז) שֵׁשֶׁת יָמִים תִּלְקְטֻהוּ וּבְיוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי שַׁבָּת לא
>   יִהְיֶה בּוֹ. כֵּיוָן דְּלָא מִשְׁתְּכַח בֵּיהּ מְזוֹנֵי, מַה
>   בִּרְכְתָא אִשְׁתְּכַח בֵּיהּ.  **אֶלָּא הָכִי תָּאנָא, כָּל בִּרְכָּאן
>   דִּלְעֵילָּא וְתַתָּא, בְּיוֹמָא שְׁבִיעָאָה תַּלְיָין.** וְתָאנָא,
>   אֲמַאי לָא אִשְׁתְּכַח מָנָּא בְּיוֹמָא שְׁבִיעָאָה, מִשּׁוּם
>   דְּהַהוּא יוֹמָא, מִתְבָּרְכָאן מִינֵּיהּ כָּל שִׁיתָא יוֹמִין
>   עִלָּאִין, וְכָל חַד וְחַד יָהִיב מְזוֹנֵיהּ לְתַתָּא, כָּל חַד
>   בְּיוֹמוֹי, מֵהַהִיא בְּרָכָה דְּמִתְבָּרְכָאן בְּיוֹמָא שְׁבִיעָאָה.‏

Comment: Can you send me a link to this?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I did it the old fashioned way I looked in a hard copy of the זוהר

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I put a link in to the place y.lub mentioned, but I didn't see exactly where in there this idea is found. y.lub: it might be a good idea to copy-paste the relevant portion of the Zohar from the link.

Answer (score 2):

This is surely a relevant passage:

“All blessings above and below depend upon the seventh day. And it has been taught: Why did manna not appear on the seventh day? Because from that day all six supernal days are blessed, and every single one conveys nourishment, each on its day, from the blessing bestowed upon it on the seventh day.

Therefore, whoever attains the rung of faith should arrange his table on the eve of Sabbath, so that his table may be blessed through out those six days [which is why House of Hillel say: ‘*Blessed be the Master day after day* (Psalms 68:2)’ (BT *Beitsah* 16a)]. For at that time blessing is prepared for all six days of the week, and no blessing appears on an empty table. Consequently, one should arrange his table on Sabbath eve with bread and food.

Rabbi Yitsḥak said, ‘Even on the Sabbath day too!’” (Zohar 2:88a-b).